Unable to re render my component in react native
PREMISE
ok so this is my code in a screen named sliding dashboard which is a child component in chatScreen which I used to call all data sources and render a dropdown with these data sources
CODE
const SlidingDashboard = () => {
  const [dashboardData, setDashboardData] = useState(null);
  const [dataSources, setDataSources] = useState([]);
  const [isDropDownDisabled, setIsDropDownDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [dropdownData, setDropdownData] = useState([]);
  const [defaultDropdownValue, setDefaultDropdownValue] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [jwtToken, setjwtToken] = useState();
  console.log(jwtToken);
  const [isDropDownLoading, setIsDropDownLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [stepsLoading, setStepsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [caloriesLoading, setCaloriesLoading] = useState(true);
  const [heartLoading, setHeartLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isDragged, setIsDragged] = useState(false);
  const slideAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(height - fixedDistanceFromBottom)).current; // Start at the bottom

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMyData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        setIsDropDownLoading(true);
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
        setjwtToken(token);
        // console.log('Fetched token:', token);
        const sourceResp = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/user/userSources`, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });
        const sourceJson = await sourceResp.json();
        const { success, message } = sourceJson || {};
        // console.log('sourceJson:', sourceJson);
        if (!success) {
          console.log("error 1");
          setError(message || "An error occurred while fetching data");
          return;
        }

        const { data } = sourceJson.data || {};
        if (data && data.sources) {
          const sourceDetails = data.sources.map(({ id, defaultSource }) => ({
            id,
            defaultSource,
          }));
          setDataSources(sourceDetails);

          if (!data.sources.length) {
            setIsDropDownDisabled(true);
            return;
          } else {
            setIsDropDownDisabled(false);
            const serviceMapping = {
              "66f61ffb-7493-49ff-8e64-ce130f4d693b": {
                label: "Connected to Health Connect",
                value: "health connect",
              },
              "86619ffb-b8f6-4a97-a6f9-fda30bca20cd": {
                label: "Connected to Fitbit",
                value: "fitbit",
              },
            };
            const dropdownOptions = sourceDetails.map((source) => ({
              label: serviceMapping[source.id]?.label || "Unknown",
              value: serviceMapping[source.id]?.value || "unknown",
              id: source.id,
            }));
            setDropdownData(dropdownOptions);

            const defaultSource = sourceDetails.find((source) => source.defaultSource);
            // console.log('default source is', defaultSource);
            const defaultValue = defaultSource ? serviceMapping[defaultSource.id]?.value || null : null;
            // console.log('defaultValue is', defaultValue);
            setDefaultDropdownValue(defaultValue);
            setIsDropDownLoading(false);
            const sourceId = defaultSource ? defaultSource.id : sourceDetails[0]?.id;
            // console.log('source id is', sourceId);
            if (sourceId) {
              const dashBoardResp = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/user/dashboard/${sourceId}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
              });
              const dashBoardJson = await dashBoardResp.json();
              if (dashBoardJson.success) {
                setDashboardData(dashBoardJson.data);
                setStepsLoading(false);
                setCaloriesLoading(false);
                setHeartLoading(false);
                // console.log('dashboard dataz is', dashBoardJson);
              } else {
                setError(dashBoardJson.message || "Failed to fetch data");
                console.log("API response error:", dashBoardJson.message || "Unknown error");
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          setIsDropDownDisabled(true); // Handle case where sources key is missing
          setError("No sources available");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setError("An error occurred while fetching data");
        console.log("Fetch error:", error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
        setIsDropDownLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchMyData();
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (dataSources.length > 0) {
  //     setIsDropDownDisabled(false);
  //   } else {
  //     setIsDropDownDisabled(true);
  //   }
  // }, [dataSources]);

  const getServiceData = async (sourceID, tok) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setStepsLoading(true);
      setCaloriesLoading(true);
      setHeartLoading(true);
      const dashBoardResp = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/user/dashboard/${sourceID}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tok}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const dashBoardJson = await dashBoardResp.json();
      if (dashBoardJson.success) {
        setDashboardData(dashBoardJson.data);
        setStepsLoading(false);
        setCaloriesLoading(false);
        setHeartLoading(false);
        // console.log('dashboard dataz is', dashBoardJson);
      } else {
        setError(dashBoardJson.message || "Failed to fetch data");
        console.log("API response error:", dashBoardJson.message || "Unknown error");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setError("An error occurred while fetching data");
      console.log("Fetch error:", error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const { dx, dy } = gestureState;
        return Math.abs(dy) > 10;
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        slideAnim.setValue(Math.max(0, Math.min(height - fixedDistanceFromBottom, gestureState.moveY)));
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if (dropdownRef.current && typeof dropdownRef.current.close === "function") {
          dropdownRef.current.close(); // Close the dropdown
        }
        const newPosition = gestureState.moveY < height / 2 ? 0 : height - fixedDistanceFromBottom;
        Animated.spring(slideAnim, {
          toValue: newPosition,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      },
    }),
  ).current;
  // ...
};

ISSUE
When I go to Add new device screen and successfully add a new device data sources increase and my dashboard should show this data but this doesnt happen and I have to press r to reload in dev mode or logout and login again in my app to see the new device data ie the screen has to re render once to show correct data
THINGS I TRIED

added dependencies of dataSources to useEffect and hit trial of other dependencies
Result: no effect of dataSources and other sometimes cause infinite re render

used useFocusEffect from react navigation so that when user focuses on screen then data   is fetched
Result: No effect as even when screen comes in focus data is not refetched

used propDrilling: I thought if screen is not coming in focus and not re rendering so let me pass  ---data from parent component ChatScreen
Result: Infinite re render app is not readable: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can   happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect,

I thought of one more fix that when dashboard is dragged to height/2 then call the api by modifying the pan responder
Result: Api doesnt even fetch and only my loading placeholders are shown


So what should I do now to fix or debug this problem

I would recommend using a data loading library such as SWR instead of that useEffect pyramid. When you have a clearer view of your data flow, it'll be easier to figure out what's wrong.

Also: what you pasted can't be your actual code, since it's syntactically invalid (see e.g. fetch(${BACKEND_URL}/user/userSources).

@AKX it is a part of code backend url is a constant fetched from env

Yes, but it was missing the quotes around it (as were many other places).

Using a data-fetching hook library like swr, the fetching part of your code might simplify to something like the following. (I obviously couldn't test this since I don't have your backend, etc.)
Note how you can load dependent data easily by passing an array argument to swr, and to skip loading that data until you know what to load by passing null.
Also note how the actual fetching logic is now in free functions outside your component.
If you did mean for there to be a dropdown to select services from, etc., you would probably hold its state in a state atom in your component.
const serviceMapping = {
  "66f61ffb-7493-49ff-8e64-ce130f4d693b": {
    label: "Connected to Health Connect",
    value: "health connect",
  },
  "86619ffb-b8f6-4a97-a6f9-fda30bca20cd": {
    label: "Connected to Fitbit",
    value: "fitbit",
  },
};

async function getRequestConfig() {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
  return {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
}

async function getDashboardData() {
  const sourceResp = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/user/userSources`, await getRequestConfig());
  const sourceJson = await sourceResp.json();
  const { success, message } = sourceJson;
  if (!success) {
    throw new Error(message || "An error occurred while fetching data");
  }
  const { data } = sourceJson.data || {};
  if (!data?.sources?.length) {
    throw new Error("No sources available.");
  }
  const dropdownOptions = data.sources.map((source) => ({
    label: serviceMapping[source.id]?.label || "Unknown",
    value: serviceMapping[source.id]?.value || "unknown",
    id: source.id,
  }));
  const defaultSource = data.sources.find((source) => source.defaultSource);
  const defaultValue = defaultSource ? serviceMapping[defaultSource.id]?.value || null : null;
  const sourceId = defaultSource?.id ?? data.sources[0]?.id;
  return { dropdownOptions, defaultValue, sourceId };
}

async function fetchSourceData(sourceId) {
  const dashBoardResp = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/user/dashboard/${sourceId}`, await getRequestConfig());
  const dashBoardJson = await dashBoardResp.json();
  if (dashBoardJson.success) {
    return dashBoardJson.data;
  }
  throw new Error(dashBoardJson.message || "Failed to fetch data");
}

const SlidingDashboard = () => {
  const dashboardSWR = useSWR("dashboardData", getDashboardData);
  const dashboardData = dashboardSWR.data;
  const sourceId = dashboardData?.sourceId;
  const sourceSWR = useSWR(sourceId ? ["sourceData", sourceId] : null, ([, sourceId]) =>
    fetchSourceData(sourceId),
  );
  const sourceData = sourceSWR.data;

  if (dashboardSWR.error) {
    return <>Error fetching dashboard data: {dashboardSWR.error.message}</>;
  }
  if (sourceSWR.error) {
    return <>Error fetching source data: {sourceSWR.error.message}</>;
  }

  if (!dashboardData) {
    return <>Loading dashboard data...</>;
  }
  if (!sourceData) {
    return <>Loading source data...</>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(dashboardData)}
      {JSON.stringify(sourceData)}
    </>
  );
};

